# Laravel: route:cache not working on production

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I've built my website on laravel, on my local machine running windows. To improve the site's speed, I'm trying to cache the routes as in the docs. The issue however is route caching works only on my local machine, not on vps server running ubuntu.

I know, the cache doesn't not work by editing app/Http/routes.php reflects the changes immediately

My laravel 5 .env looks:

```html
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=randomkey

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read this article to see how route caching works and what you have do to for it: [Laravel 5.0 - Route Caching](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-route-caching)

> Using Route Caching:
>   There's not a lot to using this feature, honestly. There's a new Artisan command, `route:cache`, which serializes the results of your `routes.php` file--it's performing the operation of parsing the routes once and then storing those result. Sort of like pre-compiling a Handlebars template, if you've ever done that before.
>   That's it! Now your routes are being parsed from the cached file, not your routes file. You can make all the changes you want to `routes.php` and the routing of your app won't change until you re-cache.

Comment: The question is - where is the cache file located? I hate Laravel docs for missing this info, the same as they don't tell where they put `down` file when I call `down` command. I had to dig the source code to find the path.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave write permission to whole laravel directory and it solved the problem

Comment: Writing permissions for the `storage` directory should be enough.

Comment: Thats what I do alltime, but laravel creates `routes.php` cache file in `vendor` directory and edits another file somewhere I can't figure. So, giving write permission to whole directory solves the problem

Comment: Strange... I knew that some stuff was cached in the vendor directory but also in a third place?

Comment: There is also bootstrap/cache folder. I too find it a bad idea to store caches outside of storage folder. Not sure, why Laravel decided to do it that way.